# Android and UNIX similarity

Tags: android, linux, unix

How similar is Android to the traditional UNIX and UNIX like systems such as GNU/Linux from an architectural standpoint?

Is Android as much UNIX as GNU/Linux? Is it possible to install an X Window manager on Android?

In other words; how much can I reuse my Linux knowledge as a developer on Android? I've only ventured into the "Java side" of Android development.

Comment: I don't know Android, but heard that the syscalls (and the kernel) are quite similar to GNU/Linux. However, the libc is different (with different APIs). AFAIK, you don't have any X11 server on Android (but something different), so X windows managers does not exist there.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Android *IS* Linux. Linux _only_ means the _kernel_.

Comment: It is debatable: GNU/Linux usually also contains bash, many GNU utilities (coreutils notably, etc...). Stricto sensu the sole kernel is not GNU. (and I wrote `GNU/Linux` not just `Linux` because GNU refers to userland GNU software).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: It is not debatable. Android _is_ _Linux_. No similar, is. It is _not_ _GNU_. Nothing beyond POSIX C API and a really few POSIX utilities.

Comment: @Jan Hudec: please give an answer with more explanation & details. I'll be happy to learn more. I don't know much about Android.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android uses Linux kernel. It should be fully POSIX1.2008/XSH (C API) compatible.

It also has the most basic POSIX utilities, but beyond that the userland is very different. And many things are only implemented in Java.

You can develop native applications for Android in C/C++, but for GUI you need to use either:

- some portability layer like [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) or [SDL](http://libsdl.org/).
- do some calls to Java to handle user interaction.

Or it is possible to install complete GNU system on Android device. The kernel is the same and the GNU system is otherwise completely separate. Ubuntu has support for such installation. It however can't access telephony, data stored in the native application and such.

Comment: So you're saying that it is very different from *traditional* UNIX, from an average developer and a user perspective?

Comment: @frodeborli: Yes, very different. All the mobile platforms are very different both from traditional platforms and unfortunately also each other.